# What is Population good for in Megapolis?

Tags: megapolis

I started playing Megapolis, it's on my android smartphone, a sim city like building game.
There is population and a population limit which can be increased by a lot of buildings. But what is it good for ? I mean from factories i get my money etc. population doesn't seem to help me much. just for achievements ?
Do i miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Population gives players access to certain production buildings

Comment: yep  I found out as well :)